# Do any Rabbis discuss experiencing sadness after producing a chiddush?

Tags: biography, chiddush, emotions

In conversation with a friend he relayed to me that after working for a long period of time on producing a chiddush or novel torah insight, once the chiddush is completed he often feels a profound sadness or depression. I am curious if any published Rabbis have written about similar experiences related to post-chiddush emotions (positive or negative).

Comment: His own chiddush or hearing someone else's? What about a case where one rabbi taught or "prompted" a student on chiddushim and his student delivered the drasha in public?

Comment: @DanF producing his own (I made an edit). I'm not sure what you are referring to in terms of 'prompting'

Comment: I wonder if that is his Yetzer Horah trying to ruin his extreme joy after working on his Chidushei Torah

Comment: I wasn't sure which word to use. But in Avot Derav Nattan, there is a story about the origins of Eliezer ben Hirkanus who was taught ideas of  Chiddushim by Rav Yochanan ben Zakai, but Eliezer ben Hirkanus delivered them to the crowd, and Rav Yochanan ben Zakai was thrilled.

Comment: @DanF understood. no, I would be looking for an example of someone who composed his/her own chiddush and then that same person felt sad/depressed afterwards (or elated)

Comment: It seems pretty normal to feel sad/bored/lost after completing a project which was energizing your life. The Talmid Chakham was getting "high" on the thrill of study and now needs a new topic to engage with.

Comment: @DoubleAA putting aside the question of normalcy; I am interested more in the documentation of the phenomenon. Are you saying it is too common place to warrant someone to write about it?

Comment: [אין שמחה כהתרת הספקות](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35870&st=&pgnum=57)